# DOJO Enhanced Grid SCRIPT28: Out of stack space error on IE Resize

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo, grid, pagination, stack-overflow

I am using MVC 3 architecture in my project. 
I have a master page and one main page. In main page i have dojo splitter.

Left pane contains Tree control and right pane contains DOJO Enhanced Grid with Pagination plug. It is working pretty fine but when i re size the IE window, it returning script error (in IE Dev Toolbar script window) in dojo.js. I am unable to debug and unable to find the occurance of error. I tried by using google but didn't get any help. Can anyone guide me to locate/ fix the error.

```
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space 
dojo.js, line 10904 character 24
```

I am pretty sure that the problem is with Grid. When i comment the entire grid code, there are no errors in IE

EDIT:
I am able to locate the exact location of the issue. The issue is with Pagination plug in. If i remove the pagination plug in, it is not throwing any errors. Are there any bugs (open) in Pagination plug in?

Thanks

Comment: Yey !!!! Fixed. The problem is with postCreate function in Pagination.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!!!. The problem is with postCreate function in Pagination.js file. Replace postCreate function function with following code.

```
postCreate: function () {
this.inherited(arguments);
var _3b = this, g = this.grid;
this.plugin.connect(g, "_resize", function () {
    _3b._resetGridHeight();
});
this._originalResize = function () {
    g._resize();
};
g.resize = function (_3c, _3d) {
    _3b._changeSize = _3c;
    _3b._resultSize = _3d;
    _3b._originalResize();
};
this.focus = _27(this);
this._placeSelf();
```

}

That is it.

For more details, refer - http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/14732#comment:9

Answer (score 0):

Well i had the same problem with a enhanced grid, and an anchor inside a cell, in ie9 just go crazy with the stack space error. I dunno where was the error but i just stop propagation the event on the onclick event like this.

```
_onClick:function(evt){
        if(this.enabled == true){
            dojo.stopEvent(evt);
            this.onClick(evt);
        }
    },
```

with the dojo.stopevent(). and call my onclick function later.